# Angular2, how to reset control (or setValue), change visibility div\span

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a search box that I want to add a 'x' reset button to clear the input. The 'x' reset button is only to be visible when the search box is not empty. I have that working if I type then manually clear.  If I use a button with type=reset, it clears the input but the event to re-evaluate the property does not fire. That is the reset buttons don't hide as they should.

I have another button with a call to a method to `resetSearchTerm()` in the component. I get the call but when I try to do `control.value = ""` the value on the control does not change. I see an updateValueAndValidity(onlySelf, eventEmitter) signature on the control, but I don't know what the arguments mean.

There is a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0wMiy4MwMbMQ11aBuUPC?p=preview) that shows where I'm at. (just buttons, red x not there yet)

Answer (score 1):

`Controls` have their own method to set values.

```
this.searchTermControl.updateValue("");
```